# How do you write a file per chunk in a Stream in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a problem where I need to read in a very large file and then print the results of a parse per chunk. Not a complete list in the end.

So far I can get the uniq results in a MapSet but am unable to figure out how to write to a file per `chunk_size`

using this method to get a unique file name

```
def new_file_name do
  hex = :crypto.hash(:md5, Integer.to_string(:os.system_time(:millisecond)))
    |> Base.encode16
end
```

So far the best I have is this which gives me a list of MapSets with the unique outcome of the chunk size. Which is a list of MapSets which could end up too large for memory to hold.

```
def parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
  file_path
    |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
    |> Stream.drop(1)  # remove header
    |> Stream.map(&"#{&1}\")  # Prepare to be written as a csv
    |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])  # break up into chunks
    |> method # method to write per chunk to file. 
end
```

What I had before was

```
|> Stream.map(&MapSet.new(&1))  # Create MapSet of unique values from each chunk
```

But I can't seem to find any examples for writing a MapSet to file.

Comment: No computation will be done until you call one of the `Enum` functions or `Stream.run/1`. So may be you want to finish using `Enum.map` rather than `Stream.map`

Comment: From the documentation https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html it looks like the only thing you could do is to convert it to a list (using `Mapset.to_list(map_set) `) and then write it to file. I haven't tried it myself  - so it may need some special care if you want to read the data back in later.

Comment: What does `MapSet` consists of? Is it rows you want to persists in new file? Would that be a problem for you to drop an example of what data you want to store in `MapSet`? That would help understanding the problem and suggesting approach

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff that is something I did try. Pawel -> yes. It is just a column of strings. Nothing special. Would just be a MapSet of unique strings. I like the MapSet.to_list but how do I write a file for each List in the list?

Comment: Can you post a sample input and output? How do you want to write the elements in a MapSet to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enum.reduce/3` with the file handle as the accumulator to open a file once and then write to it one chunk at a time:

```
def parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
  file_path
  |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
  |> Stream.drop(1)  # remove header
  |> Stream.map(&"#{&1}\")  # Prepare to be written as a csv
  |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])  # break up into chunks
  |> Enum.reduce(File.open!("output.txt", [:write]), fn chunk, file ->
    :ok = IO.write(file, chunk)
    file
  end)
end
```

You might want to adjust how you want to write a chunk to the file. The above will treat `chunk` as an `iodata`, effectively concatenating the strings in the chunk and writing it.

If you want to write only unique items per chunk, you can add:

```
|> Stream.map(fn chunk -> chunk |> MapSet.new |> MapSet.to_list end)
```

before piping into `Enum.reduce/3`.

Comment: Using the `|> Stream.map` version worked great. Just needed to end with `Stream.run`

Comment: Where did you add `Stream.run`?

Comment: at the end of the Stream so 
`|> Stream.map(**Stuff**) |> Stream.map(Enum reduce method per chunk to file) |> Stream.run`

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to write all chunks to the same file, in which case the `Enum.reduce` would be the last pipe on the top level, and you wouldn't need `Stream.run`.

Answer (score 2):

Found an interesting way to do this with the help of @Dogbert. Using Stream would lock me to max 100% cpu usage. With this I was able to reach top 256% cpu usage. This was ran on a couple files 300MB each. 30 mins to parse through.

```
def alt_flow_parse_dir(path, out_file, chunk_size) do
  concat_unique =  File.open!(path <> "/" <> out_file, [:read, :utf8, :write])

  Path.wildcard(path <> "/*.csv")
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(&append_to_file(&1, path, concat_unique, chunk_size))
    |> Flow.run

  File.close(concat_unique)
end

# I just want the unique items of the first column
def append_to_file(filename, path, out_file, chunk_size) do
  file = filename
    |> String.split("/")
    |> Enum.take(-1)
    |> List.to_string
  path <> file
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(&String.split(&1, ",") |> List.first)
    |> Flow.map(&String.trim(&1,"\n"))
    |> Flow.partition
    |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(fn chunk ->
        chunk
          |> MapSet.new
          |> MapSet.to_list
          |> List.flatten
      end)
    |> Flow.map(fn line ->
        Enum.map(line, fn item ->
            IO.puts(out_file, item)
          end)
        end)
     |> Flow.run
  end
```